# const char is being emptied when passed as an argument to Freetype

Tags: c++, c, freetype2

I'm scratching my head trying to figure out why this argument isn't being passed correctly. Here is the relevant code, shortened for brevity:

```
bool CCImage::initWithString(
    const char * pText,
    int nWidth/* = 0*/,
    int nHeight/* = 0*/,
    ETextAlign eAlignMask/* = kAlignCenter*/,
    const char * pFontName/* = nil*/,
    int nSize/* = 0*/)
{
    do
    {
        BitmapDC &dc = sharedBitmapDC();

        const char* pFullFontName = CCFileUtils::fullPathFromRelativePath(pFontName);
        CCLog("font is %s\n", pFullFontName);

        dc.getBitmap(pText, nWidth, nHeight, eAlignMask, pFullFontName, nSize);
    }

bool getBitmap(const char *text, int nWidth, int nHeight, CCImage::ETextAlign eAlignMask, const char * pFontName, float fontSize) {
    FT_Face face;
    FT_Error iError;

    bool bRet = false;
    if (libError) {
        return false;
    }
    do {
        iError = FT_New_Face( library, pFontName, 0, &face );
        CCLog("error is %d font is %s\n", iError, pFontName);
        if (iError) {
            iError = FT_New_Face( library, "/usr/share/fonts/arial.ttf", 0, &face );
        }
    }
```

about 20% of the time, the fonts show up correctly. The rest of the time they show up as arial after the first FT_NEW_FACE fails. The output of the CCLogs (which is just a macro for printf), shows why. Here is the output of trying to load a font, Abduction, for four labels:

```
font is ./Res/fonts/Abduction.ttf
error is 1 font is 
font is ./Res/fonts/Abduction.ttf
error is 0 font is ./Res/fonts/Abduction.ttf
font is ./Res/fonts/Abduction.ttf
error is 1 font is 
font is ./Res/fonts/Abduction.ttf
error is 1 font is
```

As you can see, for all but the second one pFontName is somehow emptied between being passed by initWithString, and being received by getBitmap. But I'm not sure why. What is more confusing is that it is completely random when it will work and when it won't. I'm compiling this for WebOS, and it doesn't seem to happen on other platforms (in fact, it worked fine on WebOS a few days ago) but I don't think it is a platform issue, it seems too basic. I'm two weeks behind schedule and stressing hard, so maybe I'm missing something simple. But I'd appreciate some ideas that may get me back to making progress instead of spinning my wheels.

Comment: Did the "shortening for brevity" in any way affect what happens at the start of `getBitmap`? It seems that *something* has been changed because the code as you've posted it has a `do { ... }` without a `while` at the end :-).

Comment: If you log the parameters passed to `getBitmap` *before* calling `FT_New_Face`, is the name OK or not? (Perhaps `FT_New_Face`, despite the `const` in its declaration, is sometimes scribbling over its pathname argument. Maybe not by attempting to write through a `const char *`, which seems like too blatant an error, but perhaps some pointer or offset elsewhere is getting corrupted. What do you see if, after the `CCLog` call in `getBitmap`, you dump out the integer values of (say) the first 16 bytes of `pFontName`?

Comment: By converting the `NSString *` returned from `CCFileUtils::fullPathFromRelativePath` to a `const char *`, you render the `NSString` object unused and thus able to be freed. That leaves your `const char *` pointer potentially aimed at an object that no longer exists.

Comment: There's a while at the end that I forgot to add into the shortened version, but the beginning is the same. Hmmm, if I log it before FT_New_Face, it does indeed show up correctly. It's not an NSString, I'm using Cocos2d-x, not Cocos2d.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz : Assuming this code is using cocos3dx, `CCFileUtils::fullPathFromRelativePath` returns a `char const*` directly ([source](http://code.google.com/p/cocos3dx/source/browse/trunk/cocos3d-x/libs/cocos2dx/platform/CCFileUtils.h)).

Comment: I logged the name and integer value before and after. Whenever the string came back empty, the font failed. Although once it worked and for the call before it, I got "font is ./Res/fonts/Schwarzwald Regular.ttf, -1633220164" and after, "face is ???5???7, -1633220164". It seems like the problem is in freetype, but if I pass it a string literal, it works every time. Obviously that's not a practical solution. I still have no clue how to fix it. It worked fine at one time. Going back over the commits, I don't see any changes I made that would break it.